# Using applescript to clear ITerm2 buffer

Tags: applescript, buffer, iterm2, iterm

"Clear buffer" is a menu option under Iterm2's "Edit" menu (command-K) .  I'd like to script this to clear Iterm's buffer.

I've tried, based on another site's suggestions,

```
tell theSession
select
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm2"
click menu item "Clear Buffer" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu 
bar 1
end tell
end tell
```

I've also tried

```
tell theSession
select
tell application "System Events"
delay 0.1
keystroke "L" using command down
end tell
end tell
```

Neither seems to do anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Tested under **macOS 10.13.5** using **iTerm2** *Build 3.1.7*, the *default* keyboard shortcut for the **Clear Buffer**  *command* is **⌘K**, as shown in the image below.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will activate **iTerm**, and act on the frontmost window to clear the buffer:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click UI element "iTerm" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
    delay 0.25
    try
        keystroke "k" using command down
    end try
end tell
```

**Or use:**

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events"
    try
        keystroke "k" using command down
    end try
end tell
```

- Note that *lowercase* **`k`** is used even though the menu shows an *uppercase* **K**. If you have modified the **Clear Buffer** keyboard shortcut to use **⌘L**, then use a *lowercase* **`l`**.

[image]

Comment: Your remark on lowercase letters in menus is unnecessarily explicit and does not even mention that seemingly "uppercase letters" in menus are GENERALLY used in their lowercase form in scripts, you should correct this omission . .  . Over all, not really a good answer and I can see why someone chose to downvote your original answer.